# Dynamically changing the browser title in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

i have set a title of Browser via `Application.pageTitle` property. is there any way to change the title of web Browser dynamically or as3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a Javascript function from AS3 to change the title

```
//AS3
ExternalInterface.call("changeTitle","title you want");

//javascript
function changeTitle(newTitle){
    document.title = newTitle;
}
```